# Find the area of the parts formed from the parabola $y=x^2-5$ separating the circle $x^2 + y^2 \leq 5^2$?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, area

I know the standard method when we are given equations, but what do we do when we have inequalities?

I know the radius of the circle is $5$.

I drew both of the graphs together but I don't know what to do after.

Comment: Usually inequalities of such kind just help you to locate the area to be found say you are given intersecting circle and a parabola then then many areas can be considered as the right answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For checking an inequality of an equation it will be a one of the regions the curve divides the plane into. You can check this by substituting a point. eg. Here the region will be either inside or outside the circle. To check you know (0,0) is a point inside the circle and it satisfies the inequation. So actually all points inside circle will satisfy the same. The region is interior of the circle. So you have to find the area cut out by the parabola from the interior of the circle. The area can be found by evaluating:
$2\int_0^3 (\sqrt {25-x^2} - (x^2-5))dx$

Comment: Okay,so this is the graph https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fpm0k9ejsi and I have to find the area only of the middle part where the parabola crosses the circle, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: One more question, how did you find the 0 and 3 for the integral?

Comment: These are limits of integral (it should be obvious if you have knowledge about finding areas with integrals). So I am finding area of half region(since it's symmetric) and multiplying by 2. The limits are the extent of the region (whose area is to be found) along X direction. So leftmost bound is 0 while rightmost bound (where the circle and parabola intersect) is 3 (the point (3,4) can be found from the equations). If you have no knowledge about finding areas using integrals, you should put some effort and explore the topic:)

Comment: I calculated it wrong that's why I didn't understand why it's 0 and 3.Anyway I got it right this time, thank you for your help :)